# getElementById no funciona con input tipo time

Tags: javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un inconveniente con una función javascript, tengo un input tipo "time" y necesito que la hora que se seleccione se imprima en otro input dentro en esa misma ventana:

```js
function PasarValor() {
  document.getElementById("desde_fijo2").value = document.getElementById("desde_fijo").value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input class="text-center" type="time"
                        style="width:50%;  color:#00b388" id="desde_fijo" name="desde_fijo" onkeyup="PasarValor();">
    </th>
    <td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d">
      <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width:100%" id="desde_fijo2" name="desde_fijo2">
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

La función me sirve cuando el input es tipo `text`, pero cuando lo coloco tipo `time` no me funciona.

Comment: Tienes un error en tu `html`, te falta cerrar la doble comilla de `onkeyup`. Debes ponerlo así: `onkeyup="PasarValor();">`. Saludos

Comment: Consejo: No uses etiquetas que no son relevantes al problema, por ejemplo PHP y Laravel aquí no tienen nada que ver, incluso JQuery tampoco pues el código que muestras no lo usa

Comment: Gracias Mauricio pero sólo fue un error al copiar el código aquí en mi código si lo tengo con las comillas completas, sin embargo, sigo presentando el inconveniente

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente, al menos en Chrome. Cuál es el mensaje de error? Has revisado la consola del navegador?

Comment: No me arroja ningun error sólo que cuando coloco la fecha no me la coloca en el otro input que estoy colocando, si me funciona cuando cambio el input a tipo texto, pero yo lo necesito tipo time

Comment: Primero: quitemos el infame `width: 50%` que tienes de estilo para el primer `input`, eso hace que el campo `input` de origen no se despliegue completamente. Segundo, el valor que introduces no será válido para el segundo `input` hasta que escribas la parte correspondiente a los minutos en el primero. No hay forma que el valor se escriba *incompleto*. De resto tu código es perfectamente funcional. Saludos

Comment: el evento no deberia ser onchange???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez el problema no es el evento, el problema es que el valor del campo tipo `time` será `null` o `undefined` mientras el mismo no esté completo, es decir mientras no se haya escrito la parte correspondiente a la hora y a los minutos. Pero el OP quiere que se vaya introduciendo en paralelo, mientras escribe en un `input` y que aparezca mágicamente en el otro `input`. Cosa que no será fácil de lograr usando sólo el atributo `value` del elemento.

Comment: Mauricio, gracias por la aclaratoria hay algo que por favor me recomiendes para lograr que se imprima la fecha seleccionada en ese input?

Comment: ¿Ya probaste la sugerencia de @FranciscoNúñez? usa el evento `onchange`, porque tal como parece, estás usando el icono del reloj que despliega un menú con las horas y minutos. Si ese es el caso, el evento `keyup` nunca se dispara. Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente la solucion era cambiar el evento a onchange, gracias @FranciscoNúñez  y Mauricio por su tiempo, habia intentando con muchas cosas y nada que lo lograba, ahora me pasa que me lo imprime en el primer input pero en los siguientes no y tiene el mismo nombre si no es mucha molestia, les agradecería me ayudaran!

Comment: No puedes tener elementos con `id` repetido. Cada elemento debe tener su propio `id`. Una opción es que generes una lista (Array) con los elementos de destino y apliques el cambio a cada elemento de dicha lista, en ese caso podrías usar el método [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y agregar a cada `input` de destino la misma clase, por ejemplo: `class="destino"`. Así tu lista sería: `let lista = document.querySelector(".destino");`. Y la recorres con un bucle `for`.

Comment: si la respuesta resolvio tu pregunta te sugiero marcala como resuelta, saludos

Answer (score 2):

**deberías de usar el evento onchange.**

```js
function PasarValor() {
  document.getElementById("desde_fijo2").value = document.getElementById("desde_fijo").value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input class="text-center" type="time"
                        style="width:100%;  color:#00b388" id="desde_fijo" name="desde_fijo" onchange="PasarValor();">
    </th>
    <td class="text-center" style="border-color: #9d9d9d">
      <input class="text-center" type="time" style="width:100%" id="desde_fijo2" name="desde_fijo2">
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```